# How to display a div with items from array in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a param called "exraData" which can be a string or array (depends on some conditions).

I have to display some content using java script.

in case "exraData" is a String the content is displayed well by the following code:

```
this.resulto = '<div class="avatarHeight">' +
            '<div class="avatar">' + spanPic + '</div>' +
            '<div class="info ' + company + '">' + item.show +
            '<div class="tt-hint">' + exraData + '</div>' +
            '</div>' +
            '</div>';
```

In case it is array I use the following code but nothing is displayed:

```
 this.resulto = '<div class="avatarHeight">' +
                    '<div class="avatar">' + spanPic + '</div>' +
                    '<div class="info ' + company + '">' + item.show
                    for(var i=0;i<exraData.length;i++){
                        +'<div class="tt-hint">' + exraData[i] + '</div>'
                    }
                    +'</div>' +
                    '</div>';
```

Comment: That's going to throw crazy syntax errors. Have you even checked your [console](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/console)? Is it time for a [refresher in JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide)?

Comment: i don't get any error!!!

Comment: Oka - maybe you need to refresh your javaScript.I know a good teacher-  the one which gave a relevant and correct answer and instead of mocking he tries to help

Answer (score 2):

You can't have a for loop inline. Here is the for loop outside with the desired result.

```js
var spanPic='tempPic';
var company='xyz';
var item={};
item.show='temp';

var exraData=['one','two','three'];

this.resulto = '<div class="avatarHeight">' +
                    '<div class="avatar">' + spanPic + '</div>' +
                    '<div class="info ' + company + '">' + item.show;
for(i=0;i<exraData.length;i++){
     this.resulto +='<div class="tt-hint">' + exraData[i] + '</div>';
}
this.resulto+='</div>' + '</div>';
document.write(this.resulto);
```